# Why did I need to use a notifyDataSetChanged() when I instantiated my adapter after loading in my model?

Tags: android-volley, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Goal: import a JSON using volley and setting up a recycler view to display a long list of pokemon that I've parsed from the JSON (I'm making a pokedex).

Summary of code: custom adapter (called PokemonAdapter) but it's really doing normal adapter things; it's just specifying how to inflate a new view and what text to set. My MainActivity is where I was having trouble. In onCreate, I *first* loaded my JSON dataset, *then* set the adapter object to a new PokemonAdapter. My code compiled, didn't produce errors at run time, but also didn't produce a list. That's when I learned about the **notifyDataSetChanged()** method. I didn't see why it would matter but I also didn't see why it would hurt, so I tried it and it worked.

I'm a little confused. I was wondering if someone could explain why I needed to update my adapter even though I set the adapter after loading my data. Is it because I initially declare the adapter above the load method usage? I'm new to OOP so I get a little confused with declaration vs instantiation.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Pokemon> pokemonDB = new ArrayList<>();
    private RequestQueue queue;

    /** RECYCLER VIEW */

    /* Obtain handles for Recycler View components*/
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    /** METHODS */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadPokemon();

        /* Setting up the Recycler View*/
        // Link it to XML doc to inflate recycler object
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        // initialize layout manager and use setter method
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        // Initialize a new adapter using the PokemonAdapter class and use setter method
        adapter = new PokemonAdapter(pokemonDB);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /* Load JSON from Poke API using volley protocol */
    public void loadPokemon() {

        //Instantiate the RequestQueue
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151";

        // request a JSON response from the provided URL
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonResultsArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResultsArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject pokemonResult = jsonResultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String pokemonName = pokemonResult.getString("name");
                        String pokemonUrl = pokemonResult.getString("url");
                        // Now, add this data to a pokemon object in the pokemonDB array list
                        pokemonDB.add(new Pokemon(pokemonName, pokemonUrl));
                    }
                    //this notifies the adapter that the data has changed
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("cs50", "Error parsing JSON pokedex objects.");
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("cs50", "error retrieving JSON pokedex database.");
            }
        }
        );

        // Add the request to the queue
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading data may take a while. So the recycler view adapter is probably set before the data is downloaded and there are no items to show. So we have to use the notifyDataSetChanged() method inside the response listener after we get all the data in order to update the recycler view.

Comment: The topicstarter's code is correct. The question is why we use the notifyDataSetChanged() method here.